# How to convert this code (sendMessage.php) to a function inside a controller?

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, controller

Sorry to post the code as a screenshot image. Getting error while paste the code here, so I upload the code [here](https://github.com/mfahryf/Telebot)
I found this code to send telegram message, but I want to make it to be a function in code igniter's controller. Can you guys help me?

Sorry for bad English.

Image1: [image: sendMessage.php]
Image2: [image: index.php]

Thank you.

Comment: _"Getting error while paste the code here"_, could you explain more on what error did you get? we kind of not accepting [images of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode), please edit your question

Answer (score 0):

You can create a  new action with name 'actionSendMessage', then get POST or GET data. 
Yor function(pic 1) you can move to different

`protected function sendMessage(...$params)
{
    // here code...
}`

in your controller

Answer (score 0):

You sould simply make a `send_message` method on your controller like this :

```php
/* -----------------------------------------------------
Simple PHP script for Sending Telegram Bot Message
~ Iky | https://www.wadagizig.com
------------------------------------------------------ */
public function send_message()
{
    /*----------------------
    only basic POST method :
    -----------------------*/
    $telegram_id = $this->input->post('telegram_id');
    $message_text = $this->input->post('message_text');
    /*--------------------------------
    Isi TOKEN dibawah ini: 
    --------------------------------*/
    $secret_token = "622322475:AAGE7HouAbjlr-K4AUrCBCv2bZCNZ0P7Ka4";

    $url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" . $secret_token . "/sendMessage?parse_mode=markdown&chat_id=" . $telegram_id;
    $url = $url . "&text=" . urlencode($message_text);
    $ch = curl_init();
    $optArray = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
    );
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $optArray);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    echo "<script>alert('Pesan berhasil terkirim!'); window.location.href = './';</script>";
}
```

And change *your_controller_name* to whatever controller name that you've inserted the above `send_message` method :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>wadagizig Telegram bots</title>
    <!--link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"-->
</head>

<body>

    <div class="content">
        <section class="content-header">
            <i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home / <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard / <b>wadagizig</b>
        </section>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="box box-solid box-primary">
                <div class="box-header">
                    <h4 class="box-title"><b>Telegram Message <i class="fa fa-send"></i></b></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="box-body">
                    <form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url() . 'your_controller_name/send_message' ?>}}">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Telegram ID</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="telegram_id" placeholder="Telegram ID">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Messages</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="message_text" placeholder="Custom Text Message">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Send <i class="fa fa-send"></i></button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```